# What is would be the word for deriving from experience or past performance

Tags: single-word-requests

While

empirical means deriving from experiment and observation rather than theory.

What is would be the word for deriving from experience or past performance.

Answer (score 0):

According to Merriam-Webster, "experiential" means "relating to, derived from, or providing experience".

Answer (score 0):

Wisdom?  The old saying is "good judgement comes from experience; experience comes from bad judgement."